# 12.04 Ubuntu studio PREEMPT_RT kernel options

Tags: jack, ubuntu-studio, realtime

My audio processing needs require a preempt_rt kernel. I roughly followed the guide:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild

with a little help from:

https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RT_PREEMPT_HOWTO

Currently I am using the 3.4 branch (which is the most recent at the time of this post):

http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/

I think I have a reasonable kernel config ( for my machine at least ). Multiple trials confirm I need the option:

```
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL=y
```

I have the following questions:

- Is anyone maintaining a recent CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL kernel in a ppa?
- Is there any interest in providing a CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL in the official ubuntu-studio distribution?
- Does anyone have recent config pointers for a CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT_FULL kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've entirely given up on using ubuntustudio for audio processing and gone to Planet CCRMA.

I do however want to give some resources for those looking for preempt-rt kernel config options. Planet CCRMA maintains a fairy recent kernel with a full prempt_rt patch. You can extract the config files from the rpms found here for x86_64:

http://ccrma.stanford.edu/planetccrma/mirror/fedora/linux/planetcore/17/x86_64/repoview/SystemEnvironment.Kernel.group.html

Answer (score -2):

I have personally had less issues using the low-latency kernel rather than the pre-compiled realtime kernel.  Custom kernel compilation is not difficult, but system recovery and kernel debugging can be.  I am currently using the 3.4.4 kenel and abandoned the rt patcheset in favor of the bfs scheduler/CK patchset (thank you Con Kolivas).  Btw I believe the previous poster answer has a typo, timer interrupts of 100hz are generally for servers while rt audio is more realistic with 1000hz interrupts.  300hz is used for video production/editing.  Also be aware that your ideal choice of timer frequency depends on your processor.  Do you have one core or multiple cores? Are they virtual hyperthreaded or actual physical cores.  Unless you have hardware requiring the latest kernel revisions custom kernel compilation is probably not the best idea.  If you must have an 'rt' kernel try the 3.2 or 2.6.31-rt kernel available from Alessio Igor Abogani on launchpad.  The number of options in the current kernel is overwhelming and proper configuration can be tedious and time consuming.  Fine tuning of interrupts and proper system configuration is far more effective for achieving best possible latency.